# Swipe left/right on trackpad to scroll horizontally in fullpage.js?

Tags: fullpage.js

I have fullpage.js setup on a site and have the scroll horizontally extension activated, but i can only seem to scroll by swiping down on a trackpad and I need to be able to swipe left and right aswell/instead. Is this possible?

Comment: All horizontal sliders can be swiped right or left. You can check any of the example pages  like [this one](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationH.html) and you'll see it works as expected.

Comment: not by using 3 fingers on a trackpad on a macbook though?

Comment: Oh, I missed the "trackpad" part, I though you were speaking about touch devices :)
Yeah in that case that's not included in fullPage.js, there's an [open issue about it](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1024) on the forum.

Comment: thanks, i cant see a solution though, the last comment "yep i fix this temporary put
recordHistory: false,", doesnt resolve this?

Comment: That's because there no solution provided by fullpage.js yet. The issue was never closed and it is proposed as a possible enhancement.

The only solution is for you to manually detect the swip right or left and then assign to it the fullPage.js methods `moveSlideRight` or `moveSlideLeft`.